# R select subset of data

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset with three columns.

```
## generate sample data
set.seed(1)
x<-sample(1:3,50,replace = T )
y<-sample(1:3,50,replace = T )
z<-sample(1:3,50,replace = T )
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. Select those rows where all the three columns have 1
2. Select those rows where only two columns have 1 (could be any column)
3. Select only those rows where only column has 1 (could be any column)

Basically I want any two columns (for 2nd case) to fulfill the conditions and not any specific column.

I am aware of rows selection using

```
subset<-data[c(data$x==1,data$y==1,data$z==1),]
```

But this only selects those rows based on conditions for specific columns whereas I want any of the three/two columns to fullfill me criteria

Thanks

Comment: Do you want three different data frames based on the subsets?  New columns?

Comment: I am looking for three different dataframe based on the subsets

Comment: Just fyi, site guidelines state that we only ask one question per post.

Comment: Given the tag, have you looked at `?subset` (or `?\`[\``)?

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 1 # or 2 or 3
data[rowSums(data == 1) == n,]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method:

```
rowCounts <- table(c(which(data$x==1), which(data$y==1), which(data$z==1)))

# this is the long way
df.oneOne <- data[as.integer(names(rowCounts)[rowCounts == 1]),]
df.oneTwo <- data[as.integer(names(rowCounts)[rowCounts == 2]),]
df.oneThree <- data[as.integer(names(rowCounts)[rowCounts == 3]),]
```

It is better to save multiple data.frames in a list especially when there is some structure that guides this storage as is the case here.  Following @richard-scriven 's suggestion, you can do this easily with `lapply`:

```
df.oneCountList <- lapply(1:3, function(i)
                          data[as.integer(names(rowCounts)[rowCounts == i]),]
names(df.oneCountList) <- c("df.oneOne", "df.oneTwo", df.oneThree)
```

You can then pull out the data.frames using either their index, `df.oneCountList[[1]]` or their name `df.oneCountList[["df.oneOne"]]`.

@eddi below suggests a nice shortcut to my method of pulling out the table names using `tabulate` and the arr.ind argument of `which`. When which is applied on a multipdimensional object such as an array or a data.frame, setting arr.ind==TRUE produces indices of the rows and the columns where the logical expression evaluates to TRUE. His suggestion exploits this to pull out the row vector where a 1 is found across all variables. The `tabulate` function is then applied to these row values and tabulate returns a sorted vector that where each element represents a row and rows without a 1 are filled in with a 0.

Under this method,

```
 rowCounts <- tabulate(which(data == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1])
```

returns a vector from which you might immediately pull the values. You can include the above `lapply` to get a list of data.frames:

```
df.oneCountList <- lapply(1:3, function(i) data[rowCounts == i,])
names(df.oneCountList) <- c("df.oneOne", "df.oneTwo", df.oneThree)
```

Comment: You could just use `lapply(1:3, ...)` to make the data frames and not have to write it out every time.

Comment: FYI, if you use `tabulate` instead of `table`, you'll get the exact same vector as `rowSums` - so you won't need to do the extra work later. Or, more generally, `tabulate(which(data == 1, arr.ind = T)[,1])`.

Comment: Thanks, @RichardScriven. I added you suggestion. Much better way to store the data...

Comment: Thank @eddi. I added your suggested method complete with a windy explanation. That is a great use of arr.ind. Thanks for the tip.